# Change a class parameter in javascript object

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm using this wonderful gem by Chris McCord, [Sync](https://github.com/chrismccord/sync)

My project is working fine, except for small issue relates to a position.

In the coffeescript file of the gem I have

```
class Sync.PartialCreator

  attributes:
    name: null
    resourceName: null
    authToken: null
    channel: null
    selector: null
    direction: 'append'
    refetch: false

  constructor: (attributes = {}) ->
    @[key] = attributes[key] ? defaultValue for key, defaultValue of @attributes
    @$el = $("[data-sync-id='#{@selector}']")
    @adapter = Sync.adapter
```

I need to change the direction from append to prepend.
Is there any way to change this or I must fork the gem?

Comment: @direction= 'prepend' not working?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to change that default.

1. Supply the attribute value when creating your object, the `attributes = {}` in the constructor's arguments is specifically for this:

   ```
   o = new Sync.PartialCreator(direction: 'prepend')
   ```
2. Subclass to modify the defaults:

   ```
   class Pancakes extends Sync.PartialCreator
     attributes:
       name: null
       resourceName: null
       authToken: null
       channel: null
       selector: null
       direction: 'prepend'
       refetch: false
   o = new Pancakes
   ```

   You have to supply the whole thing here. If you have `$.extend`, `_.extend`, or similar available then you could say:

   ```
   class Pancakes extends Sync.PartialCreator
     attributes: _({}).extend(Sync.PartialCreator::attributes, direction: 'prepend')
   o = new Pancakes
   ```

   to make a copy with just the `direction` replaced.
3. Subclass and set your own `direction` in the constructor:

   ```
   class Pancakes extends Sync.PartialCreator
     constructor: (args...) ->
       super(args...)         # Pass all the arguments up to the Sync.PartialCreator
       @direction = 'prepend' # Force the direction
   o = new Pancakes
   ```

   or just fiddle with the desired default:

   ```
   class Pancakes extends Sync.PartialCreator
     constructor: (args...) ->
       args[0] ?= { }
       args[0].direction ?= 'prepend' # Set the direction if one isn't supplied
       super(args...)                 # Punt to the base class.
   o = new Pancakes
   ```
4. Monkey patch `Sync.PartialCreator`. Somewhere *after* `Sync.PartialCreator` is loaded and *before* you try to use it, just patch the prototype:

   ```
   Sync.PartialCreator::attributes = 'prepend'
   ```

Which approach you use depends on your specific situation.

Demos: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/sLnhpw3z/